# How to create terms for charm?

Tags: juju

I am new to juju charms

When I tried to deploy the charm it was showing something like "missing terms"

How can I create the terms for my charm?

Charm version: charm-tools 2.1.9
When I try to run the command I get this error:

```
ERROR unrecognized command: charm push-term
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get a message about terms when trying to deploy a charm, it means that the charm you're attempting to deploy requires you to accept some terms and conditions.  You do this via `juju agree <term>/<version>`.  You can get more info on that with `juju help agree`.  The message that you get should indicate which terms you need to accept, but you can also find out using `charm show <charm-url> terms` (e.g., `charm show cs:~ibmcharmers/ibm-http terms`).

The `charm push-term` command is for creating a new terms agreement for charms that you create.  If you attempt to push a new charm to the store using `charm push` which says in its `metadata.yaml` that it requires a certain version of a terms agreement, that agreement will need to be pushed first.

The current version of the charm command is 2.2.0 and is available via snap, as previously mentioned, or via the Juju PPA `ppa:juju/stable`, with the snap being the recommended way to install and keep up to date.  The terms functionality was a recent addition to the charm command, which is why it is not available in 2.1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing via snap? That's what the [documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/master/tools-charm-tools) suggests.

```
snap install charm
```